# Are there any standalone water dispensers for refrigerators?

Tags: plumbing, water, repair, refrigerator, appliances

I recently had to purchase a new fridge. I was tight on cash, so I had to settle for one that only has an ice maker and no water dispenser. Partly why I bought this fridge was because I did some searching beforehand and found a nice water dispenser for $60 that you connect to the house water line and it magnetically attaches to the fridge. I figured that was an inexpensive way to get clean filtered water without buying one of those crappy faucet filters that I don't like.

Well, turns out that the dispenser I found had only just been discontinued. The company no longer advertises it as one of their products on their website. I've been trying to search for something similar, but no such luck for some reason. I don't know if I'm searching for the right thing. This seems like such a simple device that should be commonplace. A water dispenser that you can connect to your house water line for an endless supply of clean filtered water without paying over $1000 for a huge fridge with a screen and internet on it, things I don't need on my fridge.

How do I get my endless supply of clean filtered water without paying more than $100?

Comment: When you mention 'faucet filters', are you talking about the standalone ones that have their own spout on the counter, or the ones that attach to the existing faucet? You might look seriously at the standalone ones if you have the option to drill through your counter.

Comment: You don’t like faucet filters ? If not the same the under counter ones are usually much better than a fridge one much less than 1k But that dosent answer your shopping question and those are off topic.

Answer (score -2):

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00V2JMUHY/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_fabc_ZATBWGCPC7117FQ3CWNN](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00V2JMUHY)

This seems to exactly satisfy your criteria.